# Sass considers array with single item as an array of props

Tags: sass

For both .test1 and .test2 the result is the same (as in the link).
https://gist.github.com/programmersharp/2d83727f5a59ece5bc633edcbf4a7084

My goal is to get 1 for .test1 and 2 for .test2

Do you know if there is something similar to @each, that will not iterate through properties if just a single item in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to append a `,` in the end of your “single element list”.

```sass
$array1: ("x": 1, "y": 1),;
$array2: ("x": 1, "y": 1), ("x": 2, "y": 2);
```

This will yield the expected results for `length`.

---

## Explanation

Given the following code:

```sass
$array1: ("x": 1, "y": 1);
$array2: ("x": 1, "y": 1), ("x": 2, "y": 2);

.test1 {
  width: length($array1);
}
.test2 {
  width: length($array2);
}
```

The `$array1` is defined as a Sass Map meanwhile `$array2` is defined as a Sass List. When you invoke the `length` function it will behave differently as you may already guessed.

- `length($array1)` will produce 2 because the map has two key-value pairs.
- `length($array2)` will produce 2 because the list has two values.

Therefore to hack Sass is to force `$array1` to be evaluated as a list instead of a map. You can do that with the magical dangling `,` at the end.

Comment: how to add a comma to array (I can't add as your showed in a real application)? please have a look at the updated link

Comment: @YuryHomenok you don't need to redefine your variable, but add the `,` in the end of its own definition: `$array1: ("x": 1, "y": 1),;`

Comment: I understand your point, but I don't have a static declaration like in the example. Array comes from server and I don't know what is the length of it. So, either I can add always a comma or never add a comma. Actually seems I am able to determine when to add a comma - I check a type of variable and if it's a map then add a comma, if not a map then don't modify a variable.